# python - How to get all the <p> tags before a certain text in a webpage with beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

My website has so many `<p>` tags. I want to have all of the `<p>` tags which are written before a certain unique text in the web page.
How can I achieve this?

```
<p>p1</p>
<p>p2</p>
<p>p3</p>
<span class="zls" id=".B1.D9.87.D8.A7.DB.8C_.D9.88.D8.A"> certain unique text </span>
<p>p4</p>
<p>p5</p>
```

So I want to get the list of [p1,p2,p3] but I don't want p4 and p5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from what sir t.m.adam has already shown, you can go like this as well to get the text out of those `p` tags appearing before the class `zls`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_content = '''
<t>p0</t>
<y>p00</y> 
<p>p1</p>
<p>p2</p> 
<p>p3</p>
<span class="zls" id=".B1.D9.87.D8.A7.DB.8C_.D9.88.D8.A"> certain unique text </span>
<p>p4</p>
<p>p5</p>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'lxml')

for items in soup.select(".zls"):
    tag_items = [item.text for item in items.find_previous_siblings() if item.name=="p"]
    print(tag_items)
```

Output:

```
['p3', 'p2', 'p1']
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) in `find_all` to select 'p' tags only if all their previous siblings  don't contain a certain text, example:

```
html = '''
<p>p1</p>
<p>p2</p> 
<p>p3</p>
<span class="zls" id=".B1.D9.87.D8.A7.DB.8C_.D9.88.D8.A"> certain unique text </span>
<p>p4</p>
<p>p5</p>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

def select_tags(tag, text='certain unique text'):
    return tag.name=='p' and all(text not in t.text for t in tag.find_previous_siblings())

print(soup.find_all(select_tags))
```

> `[<p>p1</p>, <p>p2</p>, <p>p3</p>]`